# Apply function over dataframe including rbind statement

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply

I'm looking for the fastest way to apply a fisher.test using four columns in a very large dataframe

A test example using a slow for loop is below.

Apply would be faster but I can't figure out how to use rbind within an apply function.

Also faster suggestions are very welcome.

```
testdf<-data.frame(a=c(80,1,3,4),b=c(100,200,300,400),c=c(1,2,3,4),d=c(200,250,350,450))

for (i in 1:nrow(testdf)){
  testdf$e[i] <- fisher.test(rbind(c(testdf$a[i],testdf$b[i]),c(testdf$c[i],testdf$d[i])))$p.value
}
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: FWIW (I know you have solutions).  I ran `microbenchmark` against a 10,000 row variant of your data (no duplicates).  The `for-loop` took 7.323463 secs, `apply` took 7.083603 and my tidyverse solution 7.346125 obviously there are other trade-offs but it doesn't appear in this case a loop is much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try coerce the row into a matrix:

```
apply(testdf,1,function(i)fisher.test(matrix(i,ncol=2))$p.value)
```

As @Chuck noted, it should be byrow=TRUE, to test exactly the same matrix. I took a shortcut because with a fisher.test, you are testing association between rows and columns. As long as the diagonals are not swapped, you get the same p-value and odds ratio

If your matrix is indeed large, there are a few ways, one is get the unique values in the matrix, and calculate those pvalues.

The other way is to calculate [the pvalue directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382806/hypergeometric-test-phyper) but this only works for one sided test.

Comment: to generate the same answers as @mgene you need to add `byrow = TRUE`

Comment: Thanks so much, this works perfectly. If I filter the dataframe down to unique values before running and merge back afterwards, it takes it down to a manageable time for the operation. Appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: Oh yeah..glad the unique values works for you. Yeah I don't quite like doing the one-sided test.

Comment: I did try running it.  He generates... ` testdf$e
[1] 3.00086e-30 1.00000e+00 1.00000e+00 1.00000e+00` you generate ` apply(testdf,1,function(i)fisher.test(matrix(i,ncol=2))$p.value)
[1]  5.177477e-59 7.384057e-130 2.497031e-186 1.932974e-244` because `matrix` runs columns first by default...

Comment: ok yes good point. I don't know why you got such values, but in a fisher.test, the p.value is the same, regardless of whether you flip it. Because you are testing association between rows and columns.

Comment: You're right of course and the worst part is I knew it conceptually but was thrown off by the answer I got.  But it appears I can't reproduce by own so I probably munged the dataset somehow playing along the way.  My apologies although my change doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution using `dplyr::rowwise`.  I used both your original syntax as well as @StupidWolf's matrix suggestion.  On your very small dataset it appears to be about twice as fast.

```r
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371610/apply-function-over-dataframe-including-rbind-statement

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

testdf<-data.frame(a=c(80,1,3,4),b=c(100,200,300,400),c=c(1,2,3,4),d=c(200,250,350,450))

for (i in 1:nrow(testdf)){
  testdf$e[i] <- fisher.test(rbind(c(testdf$a[i],testdf$b[i]),c(testdf$c[i],testdf$d[i])))$p.value
}

testdf <- testdf %>% 
  distinct() %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(pvalue1 = fisher.test(rbind(c(a, b), 
                                     c(c, d)))$p.value)

testdf <- testdf %>% 
  distinct() %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(pvalue2 = fisher.test(matrix(c(a, b, c, d), 
                                      ncol = 2))$p.value)

testdf
#> Source: local data frame [4 x 7]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>       a     b     c     d        e  pvalue1  pvalue2
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1    80   100     1   200 3.00e-30 3.00e-30 3.00e-30
#> 2     1   200     2   250 1.00e+ 0 1.00e+ 0 1.00e+ 0
#> 3     3   300     3   350 1.00e+ 0 1.00e+ 0 1.00e+ 0
#> 4     4   400     4   450 1.00e+ 0 1.00e+ 0 1.00e+ 0
all.equal(testdf$e, testdf$pvalue1)
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(testdf$e, testdf$pvalue2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

And since `rowwise` has a status of ***"questioning"*** here's a tidyverse solution with `dplyr` and `purrr`.  See my comment above that in this case benchmarking on 10,000 rows all 3 take very similar amounts of time.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
testdf<-data.frame(a=c(80,1,3,4,80),b=c(100,200,300,400,100),c=c(1,2,3,4,1),d=c(200,250,350,450,200))
testdf <- 
  testdf %>%
  distinct %>%
  mutate(e = pmap_dbl(.l = list(a, b, c, d),
                      .f = ~ fisher.test(matrix(c(..1, ..2, ..3, ..4),
                                                ncol = 2,
                                                byrow = TRUE)
                                         )$p.value
                      )
          )
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>